# Check if select boxes are the same but skip the first item in select box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to detect if a select box is the same or not as another select box.

However I am trying to skip the first item in the list.

So if any of the select boxes (bk1,bk2,bk3,bk4,bk5) are the same as each other then I want it to say that a field is the same, but if the first item in the select box is selected then I want it to ignore it and not check if it's the same.

I seem to get everything working like I want it to but can't work out how skip the first item in the list.

So if:
    block1 = 113
    block2 = 0
    block3 = 0
    block4 = 116
    block5 = 117
then it should alert 'no fields the same, safe to move on' (since 0 is the first item in the select box)

So if:
    block1 = 113
    block2 = 0
    block3 = 115
    block4 = 115
    block5 = 117
then it should alert 'oh no, one of the field are the same' since 115 is the same in the list.

```
<select id="block1"">     
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>
<select id="block2"">     
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>
<select id="block3"">     
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>
<select id="block4"">     
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>
<select id="block5"">     
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>


var bk1 = document.getElementById("block1").value;
var bk2 = document.getElementById("block2").value;
var bk3 = document.getElementById("block3").value;
var bk4 = document.getElementById("block4").value;
var bk5 = document.getElementById("block5").value;

var test = [bk1, bk2, bk3, bk4, bk5];
var res = true; 
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { 
  if (test.indexOf(test[i], i + 1) >= 0) {
    res = false; 
    break;
  } 
}

if(res){
    alert("no fields the same, safe to move on");
}else{
  alert("oh no, one of the field are the same");selected option";
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good place to use [*every*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.every). :-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o3bcp5xj/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fix the double quotes in the closing attributes for each select:

```
<select id="block1"">
```

Just add a check for `test[i] > 0`:

```
validate = function() {
    var bk1 = document.getElementById("block1").value;
    var bk2 = document.getElementById("block2").value;
    var bk3 = document.getElementById("block3").value;
    var bk4 = document.getElementById("block4").value;
    var bk5 = document.getElementById("block5").value;

    var test = [bk1, bk2, bk3, bk4, bk5];
    var res = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (test[i] > 0) {
            if (test.indexOf(test[i], i + 1) >= 0) {
                 res = false; 
                 break;
            } 
        }
    }

    if(res){
        alert("no fields the same, safe to move on");
    }else{
        alert("oh no, one of the field are the same");
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3cq0hjh5/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `selectedIndex`:

```js
var validate = function() {
  var cnt = {}, si, dup = false;
  for (var i = 1; 5 >= i; i++) {
    si = document.getElementById('block' + i).selectedIndex;
    if (si) { //not first option
      if (cnt[si]) { //duplicate
        dup = true;
        break;
      }
      cnt[si] = 1; //mark this index
    }
  }
  alert(dup ? 'Duplicates found !' : 'No duplicates ...');
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
  <select id="block1">
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
  </select>
  <select id="block2">
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
  </select>
  <select id="block3">
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
  </select>
  <select id="block4">
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
  </select>
  <select id="block5">
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="111">Item 1</option>
    <option value="112">Item 2</option>
    <option value="113">Item 3</option>
    <option value="114">Item 4</option>
    <option value="115">Item 5</option>
    <option value="116">Item 6</option>
    <option value="117">Item 7</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more generic function that collects the selects by some method other than ID. I've use tag name, but you could use a class or some other attribute:

```
function checkSelects() {
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var seen = {};
  return Array.prototype.every.call(selects, function(sel) {
    return sel.selectedIndex < 1 || typeof seen[sel.value] == 'undefined'? (seen[sel.value] = true) : false;
  });
}
```

You'll need a [polyfill for *every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) for older browsers.